# controlling windows with java

Tags: java

Does anyone know about any way to control other windows and applications from one desktop java app? It's easy to launch apps using ProcessBuilder, but I can't operate them.How can I minimise, maximise, close windows? Greets.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control other applications with java but you can control the mouse and keyboard with the [Robot class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

Comment: Hell thanks! I didn't knew there's class like this. It doesn't solve all my problems, but still very helpful ;)